# How to configure systemd-resolved to use chosen DNS servers on public wifi

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

When I'm at home or at work I'd like my laptop to accept the DNS servers offered by the DHCP server but when I'm on a public wireless server at a cafe or coffee place, I'd prefer to use DNS servers I trust.

I can configure systemd-resolved to do one or the other but is there a way to configure it to accept the DNS servers offered by trusted DHCP servers only and defer to given DNS servers otherwise?